# Artifacts/clipping when plotting more than few hundreds of samples using `ListDensityPlot`

Tags: plotting

I have artifacts/clipping when plotting more than few hundreds of samples using [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html):

```
ping = {{0.0943517,0.0264778,0.197326,0.265565,0.076133,0.197932,0.458208,0.4159,0.0820366,0.194878,0.605081,0.477285,0.0753951,0.368409,0.418471,0.103063,0.112979,0.243055,0.129379,0.0150202,0.0817592,0.186273,0.126984,0.0103153,0.038462,0.0497663,0.0268766,0.0111087,0.00164355,0.000294625,0.000186422,0.00613739,0.0298043,0.0304066,0.0108279,0.00746964,0.0298583,0.0616985,0.0641428,0.00931524,0.0621898,0.0753226,0.0126352,0.00186713,0.00158883,0.00436114,0.019607,0.0126051,0.00412322,0.0118646},{0.0963433,0.0268647,0.205185,0.282783,0.0859864,0.190144,0.457888,0.420828,0.086147,0.193867,0.605782,0.478632,0.0803296,0.382874,0.429592,0.108988,0.11061,0.243859,0.129998,0.0154429,0.0807515,0.186094,0.12212,0.00874871,0.0416333,0.0531239,0.0264986,0.00979397,0.00131094,0.00031393,0.000374881,0.00754889,0.0378672,0.0421637,0.0170102,0.00400022,0.0263314,0.0625026,0.0681233,0.00996074,0.059824,0.0740132,0.0112224,0.000873359,0.00343171,0.00648933,0.0207257,0.0130904,0.00395784,0.0112577},{0.0952504,0.026392,0.19234,0.266967,0.076777,0.196319,0.459414,0.418743,0.084432,0.196378,0.607704,0.479995,0.0764719,0.371727,0.419097,0.103591,0.110283,0.241569,0.128957,0.0145608,0.0847704,0.189284,0.13321,0.0108501,0.0354757,0.0494618,0.0271405,0.0113022,0.00189589,0.000354823,0.00019815,0.00693357,0.0303902,0.0334186,0.0120874,0.00527092,0.0268501,0.0607354,0.065028,0.00948848,0.0617345,0.0746192,0.0151148,0.00204369,0.00155626,0.00490655,0.0202636,0.0125654,0.00401063,0.0120959},{0.237653,0.284662,0.625111,0.265605,0.768169,0.708678,0.598218,0.856453,0.624255,0.806023,0.75845,0.155717,0.480914,0.496796,0.124615,0.0348708,0.193731,0.28146,0.133983,0.237677,0.297855,0.0466519,0.157611,0.0274038,0.0555152,0.0158944,0.0716163,0.0161337,0.120926,0.0996662,0.0512981,0.182188,0.0669256,0.113836,0.175557,0.0356858,0.199561,0.0986255,0.139523,0.106157,0.118668,0.0787501,0.166228,0.085706,0.109948,0.18946,0.0777617,0.213405,0.048199,0.159011}}

Row[
    ListDensityPlot[Take[ping,{1,4},{1, 50}] , DataRange->All,ImageSize->300],
    ListDensityPlot[Take[ping,{2,4},{1, 50}] , DataRange->All,ImageSize->300]
]
```

[image]

On the top-left area of the first image, you can see a white area, just like is there was some missing data. But simply reducing the number of samples makes the issue vanish.

Here is, encoded as CSV, the subset of the data displayed in that example:

```
0.09435165673494339,0.026477808132767677,0.19732601940631866,0.26556509733200073,0.07613298296928406,0.19793230295181274,0.4582083523273468,0.41589951515197754,0.08203661441802979,0.19487760961055756,0.605080783367157,0.47728514671325684,0.07539505511522293,0.36840906739234924,0.4184708595275879,0.10306259244680405,0.11297939717769623,0.24305465817451477,0.12937937676906586,0.0150202177464962,0.08175915479660034,0.18627282977104187,0.12698423862457275,0.01031533908098936,0.03846200183033943,0.049766283482313156,0.026876576244831085,0.01110867690294981,0.0016435502329841256,0.00029462549719028175,0.00018642170471139252,0.0061373901553452015,0.02980426698923111,0.030406605452299118,0.010827901773154736,0.007469639647752047,0.029858319088816643,0.06169850751757622,0.06414280831813812,0.009315243922173977,0.062189847230911255,0.07532260566949844,0.01263517513871193,0.0018671300495043397,0.0015888283960521221,0.004361136816442013,0.01960695907473564,0.012605090625584126,0.004123216960579157,0.0118645578622818
0.09634332358837128,0.02686469629406929,0.20518483221530914,0.28278276324272156,0.08598637580871582,0.19014398753643036,0.45788848400115967,0.42082783579826355,0.08614698797464371,0.19386743009090424,0.6057818531990051,0.4786321818828583,0.08032963424921036,0.3828735947608948,0.4295917749404907,0.10898793488740921,0.11061027646064758,0.24385854601860046,0.1299978792667389,0.015442855656147003,0.08075147867202759,0.18609391152858734,0.12211965024471283,0.008748708292841911,0.04163325950503349,0.053123876452445984,0.026498621329665184,0.009793965145945549,0.0013109392020851374,0.0003139302134513855,0.00037488079397007823,0.007548886351287365,0.0378672331571579,0.0421636737883091,0.0170101597905159,0.0040002199821174145,0.026331359520554543,0.06250255554914474,0.06812327355146408,0.00996074266731739,0.05982403829693794,0.07401321828365326,0.011222387664020061,0.0008733587455935776,0.003431713907048106,0.00648933369666338,0.020725682377815247,0.013090439140796661,0.003957836423069239,0.011257689446210861
0.09525042027235031,0.026391958817839622,0.19234007596969604,0.2669665515422821,0.07677695900201797,0.1963191032409668,0.4594137668609619,0.41874298453330994,0.08443199843168259,0.19637806713581085,0.6077036261558533,0.47999468445777893,0.07647191733121872,0.3717271089553833,0.41909706592559814,0.1035907119512558,0.11028275638818741,0.2415691763162613,0.12895730137825012,0.014560800045728683,0.08477040380239487,0.18928371369838715,0.133210226893425,0.010850082151591778,0.035475682467222214,0.04946177452802658,0.027140531688928604,0.011302179656922817,0.0018958889413625002,0.0003548233362380415,0.00019814963161479682,0.006933570373803377,0.030390189960598946,0.03341860696673393,0.01208744291216135,0.005270918365567923,0.026850134134292603,0.06073543056845665,0.06502803415060043,0.009488476440310478,0.06173449382185936,0.07461918145418167,0.015114754438400269,0.0020436851773411036,0.0015562578337267041,0.004906554240733385,0.020263561978936195,0.01256541721522808,0.004010625649243593,0.012095853686332703
0.23765338957309723,0.2846621870994568,0.6251108050346375,0.265604704618454,0.7681690454483032,0.7086784839630127,0.5982181429862976,0.8564531207084656,0.624255359172821,0.8060227632522583,0.7584503293037415,0.15571729838848114,0.48091408610343933,0.49679580330848694,0.12461533397436142,0.03487076610326767,0.1937306970357895,0.28145962953567505,0.13398262858390808,0.2376774251461029,0.2978552281856537,0.046651870012283325,0.15761131048202515,0.027403783053159714,0.05551522225141525,0.015894366428256035,0.0716162770986557,0.01613367721438408,0.12092642486095428,0.09966622292995453,0.051298078149557114,0.18218792974948883,0.06692558526992798,0.11383642256259918,0.17555710673332214,0.03568575158715248,0.19956129789352417,0.09862546622753143,0.13952267169952393,0.10615747421979904,0.11866769194602966,0.07875005155801773,0.1662282794713974,0.08570600301027298,0.10994847118854523,0.18946002423763275,0.07776174694299698,0.21340516209602356,0.048199038952589035,0.15901124477386475
```

My actual data are made of $60 \times 250$ samples and whole areas of the plot are missing. How can I make `ListDensityPlot` display *all* data?

FWIW, I'm working on the Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: What does it actually take for one to reproduce this? I don't see a definition for `ping`

Comment: The relevant subset of "ping" is given as CSV data. It was extracted that way: `ExportForm[Take[ping,{1,4},{1, 50}], "CSV"]`

Comment: @user6014 Such long input lines are hard to deal with from the browser on the Wolfram Cloud, but if this is more convenient for you, I've edited the question to add a definition for my data as _input form_

Comment: add the option `PlotRange -> All`?

Comment: Indeed it seems to work @kglr! I didn't see that option (I tried `MaxPlotPoints` and `DataRange` with no change). By reading [the doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html), I'm surprised so much of my data are sufficiently far out in the distribution to be dropped in `Automatic` mode--but apparently they were. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With default setting for `PlotRange`, `ListDensityPlot` ***"automatically computes the z range and clips extreme portions of it."***

Using `PlotRange -> All` prevents clipping of extreme values:

```
ListDensityPlot[Take[ping, {1, 4}, {1, 50}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]